# When I try to use Google Sheet extractor in Bizzflow.net, I have got error Request Timeout. How to solve it?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have tried to use Bizzflow.net Google Sheet extractor. Sometimes ti works perfectly, sometimes it returns Request Timeout error message. I cannot see any details, when.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems you hit the limit of Google Sheet API. Typically this error occurs, when you try to download too much Google Sheets together. Simply split your ex-google-spreadsheet configuration into more. That meains you have to add another record to `extractor.json` into your project repo and create new config for ex-google-spreadsheet, ie. `my-second-ex-google-sheet.json`. It might help.